# systemd not starting service from ExecStart

Tags: linux, systemd

I have a service file that refuses to actually start the service specified in the ExecStart directive.

If I run exactly the same command from the terminal prompt, everything works as expected.
I have checked all permissions on files etc. but nothing I do will launch the program.

Here is my service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start pjsip Pjsua client in background
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
RestartSec=3
ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -dmS Pjsua /usr/local/sbin/Pjsua --config-file /usr/local/sbin/pjsua.cfg

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and here is the output from the log file:

```
May 06 20:27:07 vring systemd[1]: pjsip.service: Trying to enqueue job pjsip.service/start/replace
May 06 20:27:07 vring systemd[1]: pjsip.service: Installed new job pjsip.service/start as 2553 
May 06 20:27:07 vring systemd[1]: pjsip.service: Enqueued job pjsip.service/start as 2553
May 06 20:27:07 vring systemd[1]: pjsip.service: About to execute: /usr/bin/screen -dmS Pjsua /usr/local/sbin/Pjsua --confif-file /usr/local/sbin/pjsua.cfg
May 06 20:27:07 vring systemd[1]: pjsip.service: Forked /usr/bin/screen as 11355
May 06 20:27:07 vring systemd[1]: pjsip.service: Changed dead -> running
May 06 20:27:07 vring systemd[1]: pjsip.service: Job pjsip.service/start finished, result=done
May 06 20:27:07 vring systemd[1]: Started Start pjsip Pjsua client in background.
May 06 20:27:07 vring systemd[1]: pjsip.service: Child 11355 belongs to pjsip.service
May 06 20:27:07 vring systemd[1]: pjsip.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
May 06 20:27:07 vring systemd[1]: pjsip.service: Changed running -> stop-sigterm
May 06 20:27:07 vring systemd[1]: pjsip.service: Child 11356 belongs to pjsip.service
May 06 20:27:07 vring systemd[1]: pjsip.service: cgroup is empty
May 06 20:27:07 vring systemd[1]: pjsip.service: Changed stop-sigterm -> dead
May 06 20:27:07 vring systemd[1]: pjsip.service: Collecting.
```

From the above it appears as though the process has exited and I cannot understand why as it has to be commanded to do so.

If I run the command specified for ExecStart from the command line it all works perfectly. The program stays alive until I actually command it to shut down.

This problem has been driving me nuts for most of a day and I am no closer to a resolution.
Any pointers as to what I may be doing wrong would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Correction to my post: I stated that the program will not launch. It appears to launch and then immediately exits when it should keep running. I am trying to work out why it exits when launched through systemd

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the problem!!!
Because the system forks off the screen command I needed to change the service type to 'forking'.
It all works perfectly now.
Often it's the stupid things that catch you out!

Answer (score -1):

**Thanks!** I had the same problem with 'starman' (which forks itself) and that was exactly the information I needed

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).